# Unrecognized data type - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I created a database table in MySQL, but it would show up errors.  Please help to solving this issue and constructive feedback is appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE `bldsvs` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `monday` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `tuesday` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `wednesday` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `thursday` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `friday` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `saturday` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `sunday` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 'positionID` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('1','0') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Formatting the code shows you've got a ' rather than ` on positionID. Assuming that's not a copy-paste or typo, probably where your error is. If not, please include the error messages you're recieving. Thanks

Comment: `'positionID` There is a single quote instead of a backtick.